# How to access this transaction's debug log from a trigger?

Tags: email, exception, debugging

"Developer script exception" emails that are sent to developers for unhandled exceptions sometimes include full debug log.  How can I access this debug log from a trigger so that I can email it to myself for handled exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

If you need full info probably not so detailed like standard Email from Salesforce you can use Exception methods.The methods will include getStackTraceString,getTypeName,getLineNumber and all can get you detailed cause .Use in catch block and fire an email or store in custom object and fire an Email alert through workflow .

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex230/Content/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm

If you really need detailed result ,you may need to use Tooling API to pull whole debug log .

Comment: I can query ids of Debug Logs from the Trigger (Select id from ApexLog), but that table only includes already existing debug logs for users that were specifically marked to be logged on the "Debug Log" page in UI.   The other logs are obviously stored somewhere, since they show up in the Developer Console, without tracing being put on a user, yet cannot be queried from ApexLogs.  Could be stored in Dev Console's cache, I guess.  Anyway, it would make sense to have access to the current log via System or Exception class.

Comment: You need tooling API for more detailed log

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the exception, you just need to create an email through code and place the debug log into it.

```
try
{
 ...//Failure in here
} catch (Exception e)
{
  SingleEmailMessage message = new SingleEmailMessage();
  message.setSubject("Trigger Error");
  message.setPlainTextBody('Trigger error:\n' + e.getMessage());
  message.setToAddresses('myemail@email.com');
  Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{message});
}
```

Comment: I need the whole debug log for the transaction, not just the exception message.